# Click event not working in javascript in case of google ads

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to make an ajax call whenever someone clicks on an ad placed on my website. But I am unable to do so. I think that it is somewhat because of event bubbling and capturing and even tried to resolve it but this made no effect.

HTML -

```
<div id="my-snippet">
  <ins class='dcmads' style='display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px'
    data-dcm-placement='N8897.1919357DBM_CA/B10148853.136150045'
    data-dcm-rendering-mode='iframe'
    data-dcm-https-only
    data-dcm-resettable-device-id=''>
    <script src='https://www.googletagservices.com/dcm/dcmads.js'></script>
  </ins>
</div>
```

JS -

```
var ad_clicked = document.getElementById('my-snippet');
ad_clicked.onclick = function(){console.log("here")};
```

Any help will be highly appreciated as to why this is happening and how can we handle this?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` will return a nodeList, and it doesn't have a `onclick` property.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have edited my code and it still doesn't work. The main issue is somewhat different. My event is not being called due to the ad placed on the page you can easily check the issue on fiddle. Let me know if you can help me out. :)

Comment: what does contain `ad_clicked`? Are you sure that you are getting the reference of the DOM element without problems?

Comment: To expand upon what @xale94 has said, make sure that the DOM element is available. Also, stop using the `onclick` property, instead use `addEventListener`.

Comment: @xale94 Yes if you console ad_clicked I am able to get the reference of the DOM element.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have already tried it with addEventListener but it doesn't work, you can check it for yourself.